# How to run tasks with sudo from ansible in EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I've been playing around with Ansible a little bit and I'm able to launch my playbook against a vagrant virtual machine, but the problems arise when I try to do the same process in an EC2 instance. I just can't sudo any task:

```
# ansible -i inventory/staging dbservers --sudo -a "apt-get update"
ubuntu@staging-ansible | FAILED | rc=100 >>
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
```

Any clue? I can sudo with ssh:

```
# ssh ubuntu@staging-ansible "sudo apt-get update"
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-0-0-61
Get:1 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:2 http://eu-west-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [198 B]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com precise-security Release.gpg [198 B]
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found the solution:

My inventory file was like:

```
[dbservers]
ubuntu@mydomain
```

But if I set the ssh user in this other way runs ok:

```
[dbservers]
mydomain  ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```